# Angular2 / Angular4 CLI external libraries inclusion

Tags: angular, typescript

What is the difference, benefits, pros and cons of using following ways of including external scripts to Angular application (`externalLib.js` used in example):

1. Include script reference directly into `index.html` file via script
   tag:
   `<script src="../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>`
2. Set path to library in `angular-cli.json` file in `scripts` array:
   `"scripts": [
       "../node_modules/path/to/lib/externalLib.js"]`
3. Include `externalLib.js` file in assets folder

In addition, does any of above methods support strong typing of library (i.e. automatic handling of `externalLib.d.ts`?

Thank you for help.

Comment: For your last question, the way you load an external js is not related to using that libraries typings. To load typings, you must install the libraries types ex. `npm install @types/jquery --save-dev`. If you look at your tsconfig.app.json it has `"typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"]`, this will tell the typescript compiler to use all your typings in that folder. Sidenote: often times when installing a typescript library, the types will be a dependency so you won't have to manually install, but since you are loading an external script, you most likely have to install the types manually

Answer (score 2):

1. Node module folder will not be in your output so path you refer to js file will not valid. So you need to change all this file path after each build.
2. If you run build command then all file define in this section will bundle to one file in output.
3. This will include your js file in asset folder in your build output so it will need to reference separately. No bundling for this type of files.